# Getting error while entering data via AsyncStorage React-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I getting an error while I try to put data for my cart system.

I can put data when I try `[json];` but I couldn't when I change it to`[...json];`

`[json];` is giving me the last item that I put but I need all of them

```
addCart=()=>{



  const sepets = AsyncStorage.getItem("sepet")
   .then(req => {
   const json =  JSON.parse(req); 
   const sepet=[...json];
   sepet.push({isim:this.props.title,fiyat:this.props.fiyat,image:this.props.image});

   AsyncStorage.setItem("sepet",JSON.stringify(sepet));


   });




    }
```

the error that gives me "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance
    at _nonIterableSpread "

I'm removing items like this
        export default class aksiyos extends React.Component {

```
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          ApiTitle: [],
        }
      }

          componentDidMount() {


       var sepet=AsyncStorage.getItem("sepet").then(req=>JSON.parse(req)).then(json=>{

      this.setState({ApiTitle: json });


       });




      }

      removeCart=()=>{

        AsyncStorage.removeItem("sepet")
      }
        render() {
        return (
          <View style={{backgroundColor: "white"}}>
          <ScrollView>{this.state.ApiTitle.map((ids, i)=>

            <Text>{ids.isim}</Text>


    )}
            </ScrollView>
                            <Text onPress={this.removeCart}>Buton</Text>
            </View>
        );
      }
     }
```

`

Comment: what is `json`? Something like `[...{a:1}]` won't work...

Comment: Nah mate already tried it but unsuccesfull.

Comment: What is `json`? Is it an array, an object?

Comment: that's an array

Comment: Are you sure its an array - if it is you shouldn't be gettting this issue? Maybe try doing `console.log(Array.isArray(json))` before the  `[...json]` part to confirm that it is an array. It you get `false` then if isn' an array and is most likely an object. Which you can't use the spread operator on as shown in my small example above

Comment: So if its object how can I turn it to an array before the spread?

Comment: well it depends, what do you want to be in the array? The keys or the values or both? Eg: For the object `{a:1, b:2}` the keys array would look like `['a', 'b']` and the keys array would look like `[1, 2]`

Comment: When I use `[json]` and put 2 objects then I change to `[...json]` it is working fine But after I use itemRemove its not working anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the extra `.then()` when you parse your data. You need to also check for null, after removing the items, getItem will return null.

```
const sepets = AsyncStorage.getItem("sepet")
 .then(req => {

 let json =  JSON.parse(req);

 if (!json) {
   json = [];
 }

 const sepet=[...json];
 sepet.push({isim:this.props.title,fiyat:this.props.fiyat,image:this.props.image});

 AsyncStorage.setItem("sepet",JSON.stringify(sepet));

 console.log(sepet)

 });
```

In your render validate `ApiTitle` before using it.

```
render() {

  const items = this.state.ApiTitle || [];

  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
      <ScrollView>{items.map((ids, i) =>
        <Text>{ids.isim}</Text>
      )}
      </ScrollView>
      <Text onPress={this.removeCart}>Buton</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: `0: Array(2)
0: Array(2)
0: null
1:
fiyat: "12"
image: "https://nelazimsa.carrefoursa.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/turk-kahvesi.jpg"
isim: "Patates Tava"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
1: {isim: "Sigara Böreği", fiyat: "12", image: "https://nelazimsa.carrefoursa.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/turk-kahvesi.jpg"}
length: 2`

Comment: how do you initialy set this, show the code where you first save the data.

Comment: `  render() {
    return (
      
      <Card style={styles.kart}>
        <Image source={{uri: this.props.image}} style={styles.img}/>
        <Text style={styles.titlee}>{this.props.title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.fiyatt}>{this.props.fiyat} TL</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.addCart}><Text button style={styles.sepett}>Siparişe Ekle</Text></TouchableOpacity>
        </Card> 
    );
  } `

Comment: Yeap ı just putted that.

Comment: How do you remove the items?

Comment: you need check for null, after removing the items, check my updated answer.

Comment: Wow so awesome!! Thank you so much. But now I need to get rid of error when cart is emypt on the cart page :):)

Comment: TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null

Comment: `this.state.ApiTitle.map` here?

Comment: move `this.state.ApiTitle` this out and validate it first.

Comment: I udpdated the question. However, do I need to put some value inside?

Comment: please see my updated answer, regardng that error you were getting.